# How do you get Market to work when Android is Unable to Access Android Market?

Tags: google-play-store, connection-issues, htc-hero

Right now I am using HTC Hero, having firmware Android 2.1 and I have attached VODAFONE, India SIM-CARD in this phone, and also having Wi-fi connectivity.

Whenever I try to "sign-in" to Android-Market using Google Account, it is always showing "Can't Establish a reliable data connection to the server" titled error with the message "This could be a temporary problem or your phone may not be provisioned for data services. If it continues, call Customer Care."

Now what do I have to do to access "Android Market" from my HTC Hero phone?

Comment: I got the same issue, regardless of the SIM inserted or connection used (in South Africa).  The browser worked etc, but Market just couldn't establish a connection to register or login.  The device was a Sony Ericsson X10 Mini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but with SFR, in France, I have nearly the same issue ; i can't use the market OTA (unless I use WiFi).

It is due to limitation from the carrier ; perhaps rooting the phone could help to get rid of that limitation.

Comment: no need to root the phone, i just tried "Factory reset" and its working now

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is Vodafone Live can only acess wap sites
you can .... To get access to all sites e.g. Android Market, Maps etc you need to activate Vodafone mobile connect... it is little too expensive but it is the only solution....

Thanks

Comment: thanx for the answer, but i just tried "Factory reset" and its working now

Comment: Hey Thanks... I will try that also...as i also can't access android market from my Samsung galaxy GT I5801...

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify you have a data connection? Try opening Internet from the apps screen. Can you navigate to various websites such as Google? If yes then you have a data connection and the likely answer is as eephyne points to in that link.

If you do not have a data connection and cannot browse the Internet then you need to call your carrier's customer support, in this case vodafone, and tell them you do not have a data connection. They will walk you through steps to get a data connection. After that then try the marketplace again.

Comment: ya having data connection and i can access and view any website

Comment: I'm betting what Rob is saying is likely the case, your carrier is probably trying to block the marketplace over the air (OTA). I would call the carrier and play dumb, explain to them your situation and see what they say. If the carrier is in fact blocking access then there isn't much you can do but change carriers.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem (SonyEricsson X10 Mini), after trying all sorts of resets of cache's on applications etc, and the only thing that worked was to **do a Factory Reset on the phone**.

Just remember to use the Backup And Restore feature first to backup your phone then restore it after resetting it.